# Default object values in functions with default argument values

Tags: c++

So far I know that if you want to pass a default value for an argument to a function that is an object, you do it like this:

```
void function(MyObject obj = MyObject()){
    ...
}
```

However, I've come around to some interesting syntax lately, which confuses me. *What happens when we call the function like this?*

```
void function(MyObject obj = 0){
    ...
}
```

Note, we are passing an object, not a pointer. The above code compiles just fine, no errors or warnings. And this always calls the constructor with one argument - MyObject is defined like this:

```
class MyObject{
public:
    MyObject(double n){std::cout << "Argumented\n";}
    MyObject(){std::cout << "Default\n";}
};
```

Also, *where is this behavior documented* (because I searched and couldn't find it)?

Comment: C++ standard chapter 4 (Standard conversion) and chapter 12.3 (Special member functions/Conversions). And also 13.3.3.1 (implicit covnersion sequences).

Comment: You're welcome. The chapter numbers are from draft n3337 but I'd expect them to be the same in official (c++11) standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pararameter defaults to a `MyObject` implicitly constructed from `0`, by calling the `MyObject(double)` constructor. This constructor allows you to implicitly instantiate `MyObjects` like this:

```
MyObject o1 = 0;
MyObject o2 = 420/10.;
```

If this behaviour is not intended, then make the constructor `explicit`. This will also require a change to `function`'s default parameter:

```
explicit MyObject(double n);
```

and

```
void function(MyObject obj = MyObject(0));
```

Comment: Also if you wish to disable this behavior, you can mark your constructor as `explicit`

Answer (score 5):

MyObject as shown has a so-called `implicit converting constructor` from double. As 0 is okay for double, the effect you see is like you did MyObject(0.0).

Answer (score 4):

Provided that the following expression:

```
MyObject obj = 0;
```

Compiles and has a value of type `MyObject`, then a function call taking a `MyObject` will be able to work in the same way.

Imagine this function signature:

```
void function(MyObject obj){
    ...
}
```

And the following caller code:

```
MyObject obj = 0;
function(obj);
```

This is equivalent to this second caller code:

```
function(MyObject obj = 0);
```

Because the value of `MyObject obj = 0;` is equal to the `MyObject` which has been constructed in that line of code.

You are just going one step forward and providing a *default* parameter value by taking advantage of the same rule.